# What are the best, practical, resources for evidence based research?

Tags: design-patterns, ux-field, research, best-practice

I've done a little research on this and have found that places like the American Psychological Association (APA) and the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society (HFES) have some best practices, but mostly those sites are very hard to search through.

Say, for example, I had to work with and style a lot of information in tables. Where could I go to get evidence-based research on the best ways of doing this with supporting stats, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to a academic research, the best thing you can do is find a **literature review with synthesis** of articles about the given topic. In those papers you will find comparison between multiple authors and their findings in a table, which will be useful for you. You can try:

- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.bg/)
- [Microsoft Research](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/)
- [ACM digital library](http://dl.acm.org/)
- [Proquest](http://www.proquest.com/)
- [Web of Science](http://wokinfo.com/)
- [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/)

Again try searching for a synthesis article. However, the down side is that you will need subscription for the most of the articles.

Comment: These are all good resources, but I'm really looking for something more practical -- something like case studies that say "when tables are formatted this way, our eye tracking studies show they are most readable to users". Something I can use to make a business case with -- not to write an academic article. Of course the benefit here is that I don't have to waste my time / the companies time doing eye tracking studies on my own (not to mention that I don't have that technology).

Comment: Well, I've pointed you to reliable sources where you can find valid data. If you are lazy just search "eye tracking" in google scholar or just google, and you will find some.

Comment: Alright, I was just using Google before, but I asked this question in case there was something I was missing. I tried these and they aren't much more helpful than just googling the topic -- so I think I'll stick with that. Thanks for the help! :)